# Registering open generics with condition

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, simple-injector, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to use `RegisterConditional` without specifying implementing types (similar to how `Register` works, but with a conditional)?

I am using Simple Injector to wire up fluent validation for my CQRS/MVC application. Until now, registering validators (that are both used by MVC and by a CQRS stack decorator pipeline) has been simple:

```
container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), assemblies, lifestyle);

container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IValidator<>), 
    typeof(ValidateNothingDecorator<>), 
    Lifestyle.Singleton, 
    c => !c.Handled)
```

A new requirement means I need to implement something similar to valiators, but that provide warnings. I do not want to use the built in "error level" of Fluent Validation for various reasons, which means I will need to create additional validators for given types, which will of course give multiple registrations for a single type verification error.

What I would like to do is register anything that implements `IValidator<>` except for if it also implements `IProvideWarnings`, but I do not want to list each class to register

```
public class MyCommand : IDefineCommand {...}
public class ValidateMyCommand : IValidator<MyCommand> {...}
public class ProvideWarningsForMyCommand : IValidator<MyCommand>, IProvideWarnings {...}
...
// would like something like... (this obviously does not work)
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(IValidator<>), 
    assemblies, 
    lifestyle, 
    c => !c.ImplementationType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IProvideWarnings)));
```

My fallback position is to find all types that implement `IValidator<>` but not `IProvideWarnings` and pass that into `Register`, however, I would rather do it with a predicate in the registration call than a different lookup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, Simple Injector contains an overload of `Register` that allows supplying a list of types to register. While you could reflect over the assembly yourself, Simple Injector contains a convenient `GetTypesToRegister` method that does this for you. This `GetTypesToRegister` will automatically filter out both decorators and generic type definitions for you.

The following registration will do the trick:

```
var validatorTypes =
    container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(IValidator<>))
        .Where(typeof(IProvideWarnings).IsAssignableFrom);

container.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), validatorTypes, lifestyle);
```

Comment: thanks, that is much neater than my code, and I was not aware (or at least, had not read deeply enough to realise the use) of `GetTypesToRegister`. I will use this!

Answer (score 1):

My method for solving this was to use my fallback position.

Bearing in mind there are a non-standard methods in the code below (but should be straight forwards enough), it looks like:

```
 var validatorTypes = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes().Where(t =>
            t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract && t.IsPublic &&
            t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IValidator<>)) &&
            !t.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IProvideWarnings<>))
        )).ToList();

IocContainer.Register(typeof(IValidator<>), validatorTypes, IocContainer.DefaultLifestyle);

IocContainer.RegisterConditional(typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(ValidateNothingDecorator<>), Lifestyle.Singleton, c => !c.Handled && !c.ServiceType.DoesImplement(typeof(IProvideWarnings)));
```

Comment: Your ValidateNothingDecorator is in fact not a Decorator, but a Null Object.